# glCreateProgram() fails?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, glsl, shader

Note:

After digging around, it turns out `glCreateProgram()` is returning 0 all the time. I will post a fix once I figure this out. If you guys know what might be causing it, please leave a comment ^^

`context` is created properly.

`context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];`

Thanks.

---

This file is being loaded properly. It is saved as cl.vsh

It is loaded fine, but fails in the compilation stage.

This is the code in cl.vsh

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

uniform float time;

varying vec3 eyespaceNormal;
varying vec4 eyespacePosition;
varying vec3 noiseVector;


void main()
{

    int i = 0;
//    vec3 translation = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * time / 20.0;
//    noiseVector = position.xyz + translation;
//    
//    eyespaceNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
//    eyespacePosition = modelViewMatrix * position;
//    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

This is the compilation part. `shaderString` is the exact code of cl.vsh

```
 GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;

    source = 
      (GLchar *)[shaderString UTF8String];
    if (!source)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if (status != GL_TRUE)
    {
        GLint logLength;
        glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
        if (logLength > 0)
        {
            GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
            NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
            free(log);
        }
    }
```

*printing out log*_

```
(lldb) p log
(GLchar *) $0 = 0x17420000
(lldb) po log
[no Objective-C description available]
(lldb) p *log
(GLchar) $2 = '\0'
```

Comment: I see you called `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)`, would you mind sharing the output in your question?

Comment: done. its null..... please check update

Comment: When exactly is it failing? (And when are you inspecting `log` in the debugger?) I don't see it fail compilation when I try, and if you have a compilation problem you should see something from the "Shader compile log" `NSLog` statement.

Comment: I *do* see it fail *linking* when I put it into a test app, but only because I didn't put in an accompanying fragment shader with the same varyings. If you're using the template that your code appears to be from, you should see a log for the link failure.

Comment: but why is there no log?

Comment: Are you sure there's no log? Your code won't even retrieve the log if the length of the log is 0, yet when you print it out, it appears to be a 0-length log. How is it even executing the line that retrieves the log? What does `glGetShaderInfoLog()` return as the length? Does it differ from the length returned by the call to `glGetShaderiv()`?

Comment: logLength is 46551118

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some digging, I realized I need to set my context as current context. FML. This was the problem

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
```

The problem is now FIXED.

Comment: Err, this should have been a trivial issue to detect if your error detection code were written properly. You should check the state of `glGetError (...)` after each of the calls you made. You would have found that each one was generating `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` since there was no active context in which to perform the operation. OpenGL API calls sometimes fail without returning a status code, but they will flag an error state. So testing return values is only ***half*** of the picture when you want to determine if your calls are succeeding.